# Save a html from an element through JQuery as a string in SQL Database

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, html

A have an resizeable set od **DIVs** which are read from SQL Table and displayed in WebForm using LiteralControl. The user has the ability to resize the **DIVs**. I would like to update the existing DIV in SQL Table so when user access it again sees the new version. I am using the JQUERY and AJAX I just can't pass the html (as a string) as the argument, the only thing I am getting is [Object object]

AJAX and JQuery

```
 $("document").ready(function () {
        $("#save_button_id").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'CS.aspx/aaa',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: '{bbb: "'+ *html of the div that i need to pass as a string* +'"}',
                dataType: 'json',
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Server side code

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void aaa(string bbb)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into [div] VALUES(@String)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@String", bbb);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Note: Parent DIV has 5 child DIVs

Comment: `var html=$("#yourdivid").html()` and then pass it in data - > `data:html`

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it is not working unfortunately

Comment: can you show your server side code?

Comment: I edited my question to include server side code

Comment: Is it hitting server side method? did you debug?

Comment: When I pass an argument as a string, for example "arian", the function works and I can see the table getting updated with the new entry

Comment: Try `data:{'bbb':html}` as what you were doing initially!!

Answer (score -1):

Try doing 
       `JSON.stringify(htmljsondata)` 
where 
       `htmljsondata = {"bbb": htmlString}`

htmlString - html content that you want to send

What is the value you see in the browser debugger?

Comment: Function seems just to pass an empty string and therefore nothing is executed in SQL, I can append the value of this particular div to a <span> but I can't pass it as an argument to my function

Comment: JSON.stringify doesn't expect a JSON string as the parameter which seems to be what you are suggesting here

Comment: sorry, I meant the htmljsondata to be an object - that should have been {'bbb' : htmstring}